# finding permutations which fulfills given conditions

Tags: co.combinatorics, permutations

Let $K$ be an ordered finite set. Consider some function $g:K^2 \rightarrow R$ such that

$g(k1,k1') + g(k2,k2') \ge g(k1,k2') + g(k2,k1')$

where $k1 > k2$ (in order A1) and $k1' > k2'$ (in order A2) (*)

Is there exists some effective algorithm which for given function can find such orders A1,A2 where the function fulfill  the property (*) or verify that such orders A1,A2 doesn't exists.

---

REFORMULATION:

Let $K$ be a finite set.
Let $g\colon K^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

We want to define the orders $>_1$ and $>_2$ on $K$ such that
$$s \, >_1 \,\, t \text{ and } x \, >_2 \,\, y$$ if and only if
$$g(s,x) + g(t,y) \ge g(s,y) + g(t,x).$$

Is there an efficient algorithm to prove the existence or non-existence of the two orders?

Comment: I have submitted an edit of the question so it is clearer (the way I understood it). If that was not the initial meaning of the question you can delete it: I have left your question untouched.

Comment: Yes, you understood it correctly!

Comment: It's worth noting that in the lattice induced by the product order of $A_1$ and $A_2$, the point $(k_2, k'_2)$ is the meet of $(k_1, k'_2), (k_2, k'_1)$ and the point $(k_1, k'_1)$ is the join. So actually your condition is merely the definition of supermodularity for $g$. So rephrased, your question is: Is there a way, for any function $g$, to construct a product lattice from two total orders so that $g$ is supermodular ?

Comment: In fact I'd recommend changing the title given this observation.

Comment: I'm concerned with "if and only if" in the REFORMULATION. For example, if g is a constant function, g is supermodular. But the condition in the REFORMULATION is not satisfied because for all 4-tuples (k1,k2,k1',k2') the inequality is satisfied (with equality).

Comment: Another interpretation might be this: can we permute the rows and columns of a matrix to make it "supermodular"? (Again, assuming that the "if and only if" part is wrong.)

Comment: Suresh Venkat, I have already asked about this here in terms of finding such permutations to make the problem submodular one, but nobody gave answer on this. Thus, I decided to make such formulation, and as you see, there is some answer given by Yoshio Okamoto.

Comment: Jukka Suomela, I think your interpretation is correct.

Comment: @KostiaAntoniuk: I see. but to be honest, your first question was very cryptic. This one makes more sense :)

Answer (score 4):

Jukka's comment reminds me of the following reference.

If we look at such a function g as a matrix, the condition is equivalent to one in the definition of a permuted inverse Monge matrix.  There is a polynomial-time algorithm to determine if a given matrix is a permuted inverse Monge matrix (and if so, that gives corresponding permutations).

The result was found by Deineko and Filonenko (1979) in their Russian paper, and it is explained (in a more general form) in the following survey by Burkard et al.

- Rainer E. Burkard, Bettina Klinz, Rüdiger Rudolf: Perspectives of Monge Properties in Optimization. Discrete Applied Mathematics 70(2): 95-161 (1996) http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0166-218X(95)00103-X

Comment: Thnx! Definitely, I will read those papers. Indeed, I'm interested in the question is the set of permuted inverse Monge matrices a convex set. I hope after reading those paper I will now the answer on this.